# Is the sum of infinitely many open sets open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally convex space (or, in particular, a normed space). Let $(O_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be an infinite sequence of non-empty open sets in $X$ such that the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty O_n:=\left\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n: \ n\in\mathbb{N},\ x_n\in O_n\right\}$ makes sense, that is, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ is convergent in $X$ whenever $x_n\in O_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now my question is: Is it true that the set $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty O_n$ necessarily open in $X$ ? If not, what could be a counterexample ?

The question is motivated by the fact that, in a topological vector space, the sum of finitely many open sets (in the above sense) is again an open set.

Comment: If $O \subseteq X$ is open and $A$ is any subset of $X$, then $O + A$ is open. Your $(O_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is equal to $O_1 + (O_n)_{n=2}^{\infty}$, so as $O_1$ is open, it is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651133/is-the-sum-of-infinitely-many-open-sets-open#comment3367723_1651133) by [Rob Arthan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23171/rob-arthan):

> If $O\subseteq X$ is open and $A$ is any subset of $X$, then $O+A$ is open. Your $(O_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is equal to $O_1+(O_n)_{n=2}^\infty$, so as $O_1$ is open, it is open.